# How to plot large dataset with multiple dimensions in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, cluster-analysis, k-means, pca

I'm trying to plot clusters from K Means method whereas dataset consists of one million records with 60 dimensions.

To attain 95% variance, I've reduced dimensionality to 35 components by doing PCA on the dataset. So now I've to plot the K Means clusters with 1 million records and find the outliers.

`matplotlib` is taking a huge amount of time to produce the results in 2D and in addition, how do we plot a multi-dimensional dataset to 2D?

Comment: Can you show us the current code and what have you already tried?

Comment: for i in range(len(X_pca)):
    plt.plot(X_pca[i,0], X_pca[i,6], colors[labels[i]], markersize = 5)
plt.scatter(centroids[:,0],centroids[:,1], marker = "x", s = 1000, linewidths = 5) # Plot centroids
plt.show()

Answer (score 0):

For a dataset with so many dimensions I would suggest using [t-SNE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-distributed_stochastic_neighbor_embedding) visualisation - e.g. [`sklearn.manifold.TSNE`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html)

Also, for the visualisation purposes I suggest merging data points that are within a very close proximity therefore limiting the number of input to the plotting algorithm (in this way you could significantly reduce the complexity for the processing step that produces the plot).